# Unable to login new users

Tags: magento2

I recently installed Magento 2 on a development server to test it. When I create new Magento users I get `You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.` when I try to login with them. All of the new users have status `Active`. The admin account I created during the setup process works, and is the only one working.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the Cookie Domain is not set correctly. The Cookie Url can be set in the Stores Configuration under:

Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings

Depending on your environment, the default cookie Domain either can be empty or fit your domain. For example, if your domain is example.com, your cookie domain should be example.com as well.

Comment: I don't even know that the Cookie Url is, so I have no idea.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update! Currently, the Cookie Domain is empty. My store is located at `http://192.168.20.5/magento2`, what should I set the Cookie Domain to?

Comment: Are you sure this setting can have anything to do with this problem? On [this blog post](https://belvg.com/blog/cookies-in-magento-2-0.html) I found the following description of the field: Cookie Domain. If you want to enable cookies for a subdomain, enter it here. If you want to enable cookies for all subdomains, enter something like “.domain.com” (make sure there is a “.” before your domain name).

Comment: As said, it depends. Can you tell me the setting of your base URL?